# UIActionSheet in NativeScript 1.7

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

I'm using NS 1.7 and I'm trying to call the UIActionSheet. NS API already had the dialogs.action() which is similar to UIActionSheet, except it does not have the destructive button. So I would like to try to use the native ActionSheet and I have succeeded:

```
export function editTap(args: GestureEventData) {
   var obj = <any>args.object;
   var actionSheet = new UIActionSheet();
   actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Edit");
   actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Delete");
   actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel");
   actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons - 1;
   actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons - 2;
   actionSheet.showFromRectInViewAnimated(obj.page._nativeView.frame, obj.ios, true);
}
```

However, I don't know how to implement the callback (which is UIActionSheetDelegate I guess) that responds to what users have clicked. There is a function in iOS API called `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex`but at I don't know how to call it through javascript (or typescript). Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another way to implement this and succeeded by using UIAlertController as UIActionSheet has been deprecated since iOS 8.3. This is what I have done:

```
    var alertController = UIAlertController.alertControllerWithTitleMessagePreferredStyle("title", "message", UIAlertControllerStyle.UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet);
    var editAction = UIAlertAction.actionWithTitleStyleHandler("Edit", UIAlertActionStyle.UIAlertActionStyleDefault, (arg: UIAlertAction) => {
        //code implementation here
    });
    var deleteAction = UIAlertAction.actionWithTitleStyleHandler("Delete", UIAlertActionStyle.UIAlertActionStyleDestructive, (arg: UIAlertAction) => {
        //code implementation here
    });
    var cancelAction = UIAlertAction.actionWithTitleStyleHandler("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.UIAlertActionStyleCancel, (arg: UIAlertAction) => {
        //code implementation here
    });

    alertController.addAction(editAction);
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction);
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction);
    var currentPage = topmost().currentPage;
    var viewController: UIViewController = currentPage.ios;
    viewController.presentModalViewControllerAnimated(alertController, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

A sample code for NativeScript marshalling (data conversion) for Objective-C to JavaScript can be found [at this link](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/how-to/ObjC-Subclassing#calling-base-methods-Protocol)

Basically, what you need in order to implement your delegate is something like this:

```
var UIActionSheetDelegate = UIActionSheet.extend({
    clickedButtonAtIndex(buttonAtIndex) {
        // clickedButtonAtIndex code implementation here
    }
}, {
    protocols: [UIActionSheetDelegate]
});
```

Comment: There is an error `Protocols "undefined" is not protocol...` when I tried your solution. However, I have found another way to do this by using UIAlertController as UIActionSheet has been deprecated since iOS 8.3. Thank you anyway, especially the link for Obj-C to JS conversion.